# Express app getting disconnected right after the connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I created a rest api with Express. on my server.js the i have my mysql connection.. though the connection is made at first. It's working on my local machine properly but when i deployed on AWS EC2 service then i am facing this problem..

server.js

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'myusername',
   password: 'mypassword',
   database: 'mydatabasename'
 });

connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('connected!');
});

module.exports = connection;
```

i tried pm 2 handledisconnect() following other project function none worked.getting following error...

> restapi@0.0.0 start /home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi
>   npm start

connected!
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket. (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
    at Socket. (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1168:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:426:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.end (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
    at Socket. (/home/bcs_quiz_console/bcs-preparation-backend/restapi/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}

Thank anyone who can help in advance..

Comment: do you have MySQL installed in ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes i have installed mysql on EC2

Comment: are you able to login to MySQL for given username and password from terminal?

Comment: @SandeepPatel from terminal cannot.. but i use vesta panel i created the database with same username and password that i provided. And It also get connected for at least 5-10 (most cases 15) second then disconnect so i assumed the username and password is alright.